# Does the method popViewControllerAnimated: act different than the Back button of the NavigationController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontroller, popviewcontrolleranimated

In my Application i have a container `ViewController` which is the `RootView` of an `UINavigationController`.

I transit between various `Child ViewControllers` through a `segmentedControl` in the `Toolbar` of the `UINavigationController`.

One of the `Child views` pushes another `View` on the `NavigationController`, keeping the `ToolbarItems`.

Using the Back Button I get the desired behaviour of returning to the `RootViewController`, but any try of going back programatically won't change the `view`.
`popViewControllerAnimated` always takes the `topViewController` of the Stack but nether updates the View. `viewWillAppear` of the `Container ViewController` won't be called this way.
So i am wondering if the Back button does any additional Stuff which won't happen in with `popViewControllerAnimated`.
Also `popViewControllerAnimated:YES` will freeze the app without throwing an error.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Edit:
Ok one test case was a little of.

A popViewControllerAnimated in the topViewController of the Stack works as normal. But a call to popViewControllerAnimated through the SegmentedControll does not.

I realise the way i wrote this might be a little confusing, i will try to make this all a little clearer later.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was a timing issue. I changed the ChildViews of the container `ViewController` directly after the call to `popViewControllerAnimated`.